# Java - how to read a string OR that the user hit enter

Tags: java, input, console

scanner doesn't seem capable of letting me know the user hit enter rather than keying something in - my program just hangs forever on scanner.

I know I used to code something else a few years ago that worked, but I lost all my old code and am reinventing the wheel and I have searched and searched for a couple of hours and everyone is hooked on scanner.

Here is my code - I guess I'll have to change it so when the user is done they enter something like NO - because this doesn't work when they just hit enter, otherwise it works fine. (like if I comment out the scanner and just have the answer = "" when I was going to just hit enter - that works fine).

```
*/
 public static void main(String[] args) {
...
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
...
System.out.println("\nIf you are guessing(know) any letters, now enter the CRYPTO letter you are guessing (not what it is)");
    System.out.println("Just hit Enter if you are not entering any");

    // get their input as a String
    String answer = scanner.next();
    while (answer.length() > 0) {
        code = new WordChars(answer.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("\nNOW enter the real letter you are guessing or know " + code.theWord + " is");
        answer = scanner.next();
        //answer = "p";
        if (answer.length() < 1) {
            System.out.println("\nIf you hit enter again we are cancelling that character map, else enter the character");
            answer = scanner.next();
            //answer = "";
        } else {
            letter = new WordChars(answer.toUpperCase());
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < theTemplate[j].theChars.length; k++) {
                    if (theTemplate[j].theChars[k] == code.theChars[0]) {
                        theTemplate[j].theKnownChars[k] = letter.theChars[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            code = null;
            letter = null;
            System.out.println("\nIf you are guessing(know) any MORE letters, now enter the CRYPTO letter you are guessing (not what it is)");
            System.out.println("Just hit enter is you are not entering any");
            answer = scanner.next();
            //answer = "";  
        }
    }
```

...

So basically all works EXCEPT for stopping the whole thing but just hitting enter when prompted, and then answer being empty.  I know there is (a somewhat lengthier) way of coding this but I've forgotten what it is.

Comment: Does my answer fit your needs Nancy?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to check if the user presses a letter, number, or enter:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
if (s.matches("[a-zA-z]")) {
    System.out.println("You pressed a letter");
} else if(s.matches("[1-9]")){
    System.out.println("You pressed a number");
} else {
    System.out.println("You pressed enter");
}
in.close();
```

To read enter, all you have to do is use `scanner.nextLine()`, instead of `scanner.next()`.